# Output of following code

Tags: c, operators

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i=-3,j=2,k=0,m;
m= ++i && ++j || ++k;
printf("%d %d %d %d",i,j,k,m);
return 0;
}
```

Could someone tell how does is the m evaluated. I am confused as how k remain '0'

Answer (score 4):

```
m= ++i && ++j || ++k;
```

First, `++i && ++j` takes effect, `i` become `-2` and `j` become `3`, which makes `++i && ++j` non-zero, so `m` will be evaluated to `1` (true) because of short-circuit. All the later expression(`++k`) won't be executed.

Comment: ++j is executed because you have ++i `&&` ++j as you said i=-2 non zero therefore no short circuit

Comment: `++j` will be evaluated

Comment: @Light Right, I can't believe I said that.

Comment: @YuHao Doesn't `++` pre-increment has the highest precedence, it is violated in this case? I am taken aback a bit now!

Comment: @Light Yes, but that only means that the expression is the same as `(++i) && (++j) || (++k)`. Here short-circuit means there's a sequence point after `&&` evaluates.

Comment: @YuHao But `++` has precedence over the logical operators I expected the pre-increments to be evaluated before the logical operations!

Comment: @Light No, precedence and associativity is about grouping, not execution sequence, search "sequence point".

Answer (score 2):

```
m= (    (++i) && (++j)   ) || ++k;
          |        |       
          |        |       
   (   T (-2) AND T(3)   ) OR something
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              T            OR something
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        
                       = T
                       = 0
```

Changing `j=-1`

```
m= (    (++i) && (++j)   ) || ++k;
          |        |       
          |        |       
   (   T (-2) AND T(0)   ) OR something
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              F            OR T (0)      //++k evaluated
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        
                       = T
                       = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialized Values:
`int i=-3,j=2,k=0,m;`

Original expression:
`m= ++i && ++j || ++k;`

With implicit operator precedence:
`m= (++i && ++j) || ++k;`

The expression evaluates left to right. What you need to understand is how [Short Circuit Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) works.

**Evaluation Walkthrough:**

1. `i` gets incremented (`-3 --> -2`)
2. The logical AND operator is evaluated (`&&`). It checks if the left hand argument `i` evaluates to `true` (`i!=0`). If the left hand side evaluates to `false`, the and operator short circuits the evaluation and returns `false` (`0`). This doesn't happen because `i==-2`, so the right hand side `(++j)` is also evaluated.
3. `j` get incremented (`2 --> 3`)
4. Logical AND finishes its right hand side evaluation `i!=0 && j!=0`. It returns `true` (`!0`).
5. The logical OR operator is evaluated (`||`). It checks if the left hand argument `(++i && ++j)` evaluates to `true` (`!0`). If the left hand side evaluates to `true`, the and operator short circuits the evaluation and returns `true` (`!0`). This happens because `++i && ++j` already evaluated `true`. Consequent `k++` never executes!
6. Logical OR (`||`) assigns the evaluated value (`!0`) to `m`. `m!=0` after the expression evaluates.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of short circuting. If you know about how an OR expression is evaluated, you will get the hang of this expression. `1 OR Anything is always 1`

```
int i=-3,j=2,k=0,m;
m= ++i && ++j || ++k;

`-2 && +3 is +1 therefore +1 OR anything is 1.` Hence C skips evaluation of k.
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer would be

-2 3 0 1

Explanation :

There are two basic facts that work here

FACT 1 :

Whenever there is an expression with PRE-INCREMENT operator, All these operators would be operated on the corresponding variables first, and then the whole expression would be evaluated with updated values of variables.

FACT 2

whenever there is an expression having OR operator, If first operator is true(or non zero in some cases), second operator wouldn't be executed. 
for example

```
   a=2;
   b=2;
   c=3;
   boolean k = c || a+b ;
```

The values of variable k would be true and the expression "a+b" wouldn't be even considered as c is non zero.

In your case variable i and j would be incremented first and the expression would be

```
 -2 && 3 || ++k
```

Note : variable k wouldn't be incremented here because in case of OR logical operator Left operand would be solved completely first. 
Left operand would would be then TRUE because both -2 and 3 are non zero .

so the whole expression would be

```
  TRUE || ++k
```

This wouldn't be evaluated further because no matter what, the result always be TRUE .

as we are assigning this result (TRUE) to an integer variable, it would be 1.

Hence the answer is ....